# DynamoDB C# cannot convert string to integer error

Tags: amazon-web-services

I created a DynamoDb using NET and able to getitem, which is not an empty list. I get a status 400 error on the putitem using Postman. This is the error:

```
    "errors": {
        "id": [
            "Could not convert string to integer: 9134d3a0-a6bf-4409-87b3-d9fad02bd31c. Path 'id', line 2, position 44."
        ]
    },
```

This is the body I use for the post:

```
{
    "id":"9134d3a0-a6bf-4409-87b3-d9fad02bd31c",
    "replyDateTime": "63669789320007900",
    "body":"a good body",
    "title":"best title",
    "creator": " James"
}
```

This is my createtable code:

```
 var request = new CreateTableRequest
            {
                AttributeDefinitions = new List<AttributeDefinition>
                {
                    new AttributeDefinition
                    {
                        AttributeName = "Id",
                        AttributeType = "S"
                    },
                    new AttributeDefinition
                    {
                        AttributeName = "ReplyDateTime",
                        AttributeType = "S"
                    }
                },
                KeySchema = new List<KeySchemaElement>
                {
                    new KeySchemaElement
                    {
                        AttributeName = "Id",
                        KeyType = "HASH" // Partition Key
                    },
                    new KeySchemaElement
                    {
                        AttributeName = "ReplyDateTime",
                        KeyType = "Range" // Sort Key
                    }
                },
```

this is the putitem code:

```
public async Task AddNewEntry(string id, string replyDateTime, string body, string title, string creator)
        {
            var queryRequest = RequestBuilder(id, replyDateTime, body, title, creator);

            await PutItemAsync(queryRequest);
        }

        private PutItemRequest RequestBuilder(string id, string replyDateTime, string body, string title, string creator)
        {
            var item = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
            {
                {"Id", new AttributeValue {S = id}},
                {"ReplyDateTime", new AttributeValue {S = replyDateTime}},
                {"Body", new AttributeValue {S = body}},
                 {"Creator", new AttributeValue {S = creator}},
                  {"Title", new AttributeValue {S = title}}
            };

            return new PutItemRequest
            {
                TableName = "BlogDynamoDbTable",
                Item = item
            };
        }

        private async Task PutItemAsync(PutItemRequest request)
        {
            await _dynamoClient.PutItemAsync(request);
        }
    }
```

I believe I made the primary key a string. Why is an integer even mentioned in the error message?

Comment: `{"Id", new AttributeValue {N = id}}` Shuodn't there be an S, not N, for number?

Comment: @Marcin, thanks. I tried it with S=id and get the same error. I updated the question to indicate that.

Answer (score 0):

I found my error. The model file was defining id as an integer. Grrr
I changed it to string and it posts.

```
public class Item
    {
       [Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBHashKey]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBRangeKey]
        public string ReplyDateTime { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Creator { get; set; }
    }
```